# Kivy installation error on Python v 3.11.2 and Windows 11 22H2 OS Build: 22621.1265

Tags: python, powershell, winforms, kivy, kivy-language

I tried installing Kivy on a new Windows 11 Installation. Even after I have satisfied the required dependencies, I keep getting an installation error. Below is the response I received.

```
      Updated build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\include\config.h
      Updated C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-878mjsbv\kivy_43cb622015164809b06a8b1af4948f34\kivy\include\config.h
      Updated build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\include\config.pxi
      Updated C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-878mjsbv\kivy_43cb622015164809b06a8b1af4948f34\kivy\include\config.pxi
      Updated build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\kivy\setupconfig.py
      Updated C:\Users\nadee\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-878mjsbv\kivy_43cb622015164809b06a8b1af4948f34\kivy\setupconfig.py
      Detected compiler is msvc
       error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.34.31933\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
Failed to build kivy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no wheel for Kivy and Python 3.11 yet.
You have to build Kivy from source.  You can do that using the following commands.  I am doing it in a virtual environment to keep it separate from the main system.

```
python3.11 -m virtualenv Kivy_Py3.11
cd Kivy_Py3.11
source bin/activate
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git
cd kivy
python -m pip install -e ".[base]"
python -m pip install kivymd
pip freeze
```

Kivy will now be installed and the 'pip freeze' should show:  (version number will probably be different)

```
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
docutils==0.19
idna==3.4
-e git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@a7c66880270a93821e1f8ecd613409f008fd2ce8#egg=Kivy
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
KivyMD==1.1.1
Pillow==9.3.0
Pygments==2.13.0
requests==2.28.1
urllib3==1.26.13
```

If you want to use the nightly build of Kivy that is more compatiable with Python 3.11 then you can just run these command.

```
python3.11 -m pip install kivy --pre --no-deps --index-url  https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
python3.11 -m pip install "kivy[base]" --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
python3.11 -m pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Kivy cannot be installed on python 3.11. In order to install it you need to downgrade to a lower version of python.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Run this command:

```
python -m pip install kivy --pre --no-deps --index-url  https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```